# Typo error on printed double sided flyer that client approved. Should the designer pay?

Tags: print-design, design-principles, business, client-relations

A client sent the text which was copied and pasted for a flyer design. The client approved the final file for print. The flyer is  printed but does have a typo error. Is the designer responsible for not spotting it? Should the designer have to pay?

Comment: You're a designer, not a copy writer.  If you catch copy mistakes and bring them to the client's attention then thats all well and good and I'm sure they'll be happy you did.  If they approved the design for print, however, then the burden is theirs to bear, in my opinion anyway.

Comment: Usually as a designer you would send a proof. I usually send this over and ask its approval before preparing the final files. In the proof I state that any typos beyond that point are solely the responsibility of the client. We are designers, we shouldn't have to be responsible for the clients copy or grammatical errors

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and thoughts, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion in this case is that the designer is not responsible, since it was client-supplied text, and moreover, the client proofed and approved the final file for print.

That said, many cases like this hinge on a couple things:

1) The designer/client agreement beforehand regarding this type of thing (if there was one). If it was explicitly stated that once client gives final approval, all responsibility is placed on the client, there's no questions afterward. I try to put that in writing for all my clients.

2) the relationship with the client. If it's a highly desired client, the designer may want to offer to split the reprint cost to keep client happy. But based on the facts you state, I see no reason why the designer should have to cover the entire cost.

Comment: +1. Read Your Contract. If your contract states that final approval is on Client and Client is responsible for typos, it's not Designer's fault. Whether Designer chooses to eat the occasional typo to maintain a relationship is up to Designer and Designer's budget.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and thoughts, much appreciated.